# Add craco webpack plugin by condition for create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I am using [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) with create react app and I would like to add a plugin only in DEV mode  or by ENV Var

my craco.config looks is:

```
const path = require('path');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    webpack: {
      alias: {
        environment: path.join(
          __dirname,
          'src',
          'environments',
          process.env.CLIENT_ENV || 'production'
        )
      }
      //   plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
    },
    jest: {
      configure: {
        testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/environments/'],
        moduleNameMapper: {
          environment: '<rootDir>/src/environments/test'
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

so I would like this BundleAnalyzerPlugin. only if the ENV param x =true or if NODE_ENV=test

while I trying to push to plugin array I got that plugin I undefined

```
module.exports.webpack.plugins.push(plugin)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set an environment variable right before any script command. For example, in your package.json, add a new line in the `scripts` paragraph that sets some variables:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "analyzer": "env NODE_ENV=production ANALYZER=test yarn start"
 }
```

In `craco.config.js` you can simply use:

```
 plugins: process.env.ANALYZER === 'test' ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : []
```

Now, running `npm run analyzer` will both, set node env to `production`, set a variable `ANALYZER` to `test` (used later on) and load the craco config, that will start both the webpack server and the analyser.

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditions from craco like `when`, `whenDev`, `whenProd`, `whenTest`

```
 webpack: {
    plugins: [...whenDev(() => [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()], [])]
},
```